# Are all Universal Windows Platform APIs available to side-loaded apps?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-store

I have a vague recollection of reading somewhere in Microsoft's documentation (it might have been to do with BLE APIs), that some APIs are only available to apps *downloaded from the Windows Store*. I just searched again and can't find anything. Did I misremember or is this the case for some APIs?

Comment: I can't remember either, but it is entirely possible that the documentation said this at one point as a way of clarifying which API functions were available only to UWP apps. Arguably bad wording in documentation intended for developers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any APIs that aren't available in a side-loaded application, but APIs from the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.aspx) for example may not function in a meaningful way (like `ListingInformation` wouldn't be useful).